# How do I fix "Generator MinGW Makefiles does not support platform specification, but platform x64 was specified?

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw, blender, dlib

I'm currently trying to install [Morse](https://github.com/morse-simulator/morse) (an open-source 3D robot simulator based on Blender) for a project.
Whenever I ran the winbuild.bat, I used to get the "No CMake_C_Compiler could be found" error - I more or less "fixed" this by adding -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/c/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/c/MinGW/bin/g++.exe to the file. However, now I get

```
Generator

    MinGW Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.
```

I have tried re-installing visual studio, MinGW and CMake several times, as doing so seemed to be the best solutions I've found online so far, but nothing worked. Does anybody know how I can fix this, or at least tell me what exactly is wrong here? So far, I've only found people who got "Generator NMake Makefiles..." instead of MinGW.

By the way, I also am unable to install dlib using pip, if this is related anyhow; `pip install dlib` yields "No CMake_C_Compiler could be found". I have added both CMake and MinGW/bin to path.

Comment: Platform specification is valid only for **Visual Studio generators**, it is not supported neither by MinGW nor by NMake generators. If you have Visual Studio installed, specify appropriate [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#visual-studio-generators) with `-G` option. Note, that using Visual Studio generator implies running `cmake` under effect of `vcvarsall.bat` script shipped with your Visual Studio or under Visual Studio command line.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use plain MinGW, it only supports Windows 32-bit.
The newer MinGW-w64 is available for both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit.
You can download a build of MinGW-w64 from http://winlibs.com/ that doesn't require installation, just unzip it. This means you can try it without throwing away your current MinGW folder.